# Set Dynamic Id to `Div` inside table

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a `DataTable` and according to number of rows in that table I am generating some `aspx` code as below:

```
 <%if (dtLevel2.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr2 in dtLevel2.Rows)
     { %>
          <div> 
              ** Some Code **
          </div>
  <% }
 } %>
```

As you can see, number of `div`'s generated depends upon no. of rows in table.
I want to generate ID for each div but I dont know how to do it.
Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop and instead of `foreach`. That way, you will have an index and can do something like

```
<div id="${index}">
   <!-- code -->
</div>
```

P.S. Sorry I am not sure about asp syntax. But you should get the idea.